# Handle unicode string right

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I have an API which usually gets a request with string containing digits, "/", "." and latin characters. Like this:

```
sq = u'/h97/D2/SNB6E961/2/B92TS667RE.html'
```

In some cases I have to generate a message with this string like this:

```
 resp = unicode('Not found for string %s' % sq)
```

But sometimes this API gets broken strings like this:

```
sq = u'/h97/D2/SNB6E961/2/100%\u0445200B92TS667RE.html'
```

And in this case I cant make correct response because of unicode error:

```
r = u'/h97/D2/SNB6E961/2/100%\u0445200B92TS667RE.html'.encode('utf-8')
msg = 'Not found for string %s' % r
resp = unicode(msg)
```

And last string going to cause an exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I need to add some operation to avoid cases like this but do not change "usual" path of execution. So I have to find any way to add that broken string to response.

Of course I can just add try-except and make a response without that string.

But I'm not an expert with python unicode problems, so may be there is some more elegant way to not create new kind of response and keep only one line of execution?

Comment: Mmmh... not an expert myself either but the `unicode()` documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html says that if you omit the `encoding` parameter you will get the exception. In your example, `r` is already known to be utf-8 so you could specify it as such to avoid the exception.

Comment: You're casting `r` to `str` first (using `.encode('utf8')`), then later you decode `msg` again (with `unicode()`). If need `unicode` in the end, then just keep it `unicode` and skip the forth and back. Or just use Python 3, it's a quite a bit clearer there.